# How to clip a polyline network by a polygon

Tags: polygon, line, clip

I work in ArcGIS Pro 3.0. I have a polyline feature class of roads. I have a polygon feature class of counties. I need to clip the roads by counties so that each county has a record of how many kilometres of roads there are in it.
Is there a way to make a polygon feature class (about 200 records) clip the roads polyline feature class?

Comment: Have a look at the help file on the Identity or Intersect tool.

Comment: Identity tool helped me do it.